# puppet errror to install tomcat6 module

Tags: puppet

i am trying to install the tomcat6 module into the agent.i already download module from puppetlab.and try to connect to server i am getting the following error.

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on
 SERVER: No matching value for selector param 'undef' at
/etc/puppet/modules/yum_priorities/manifests/init.pp:19..
```

the init.pp file contains for yum_priorities

> ```
> 14    class yum_priorities {
> 15    
> 16        $yum_priorities = $lsbmajdistrelease ? {
> 17          /4|6/ => 'yum-plugin-priorities',
> 18          '5'       => 'yum-priorities',
> 19        }
> 20    
> 21        package {$yum_priorities :
> 22          ensure    => installed,
> 23        }
> ```

my site.pp file in manifest

> ```
>  27   node 'puppet_client'
>  28   {
>  29       include tomcat6
>  30   }
> ```

tomcat have dependency on yum_priorities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that `$lsbmajdistrelease` is not defined.

Try to add the proper scope (global): `$::lsbmajdistrelease`

Facter should give you that global variable, you can run facter manually and see if there's an error.

```
facter lsbmajdistrelease
```

Comment: Convention is to always define a default case for your selectors too, to handle exactly these instances.

Answer (score 2):

I can't add comments so I have to "answer it" :). Anyways, as answered by Ger Apeldoorn facter can't get value of `lsbmajdistrelease`.

On Redhat/CentOS find which package you are missing:

```
yum whatprovides lsb_release
```

Or simply install it:

```
yum install redhat-lsb-core
```

This will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Print out a notify statement on line 20 inside class yum_priorities. Something like :

```
notify {"I AM SEEING THIS ... ${yum_priorities}" :}
```

and also somewhere inside the module tomcat6.

and check what you get when you run puppet agent. If it is empty means it hasn't been propagated properly.

One other comment is that, it may not be a good coding example to have the same name for a class and a variable, i.e. yum_priorities.